# EntityManagerFactory must not be null after migrate to hibernate 5.2.6 in spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, hibernate-5.x

I using Hibernate in my Spring boot App after migrate from Hibernate 5.0.11 to 5.2.6.Final .i get EntityManagerFactory must not be null exception 
this is my codes

My Hibernate Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

My Repository Class

```
@Repository
public class GenericRepository{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

}
```

Exception is this

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1647)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **EntityManagerFactory must not be null**
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject(HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.java:46)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject(HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my configuration to this  for create sessionfactory

```
    @Inject
    public DataSource dataSource;


    @Inject
    public JpaProperties prop;


    @Bean("sessionFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.roshan" });
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedPackages(new String[] { "org.roshan" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    private  Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.putAll(prop.getProperties());
        p.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, prop.getHibernate().getDdlAuto());
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove @Autowired from transactionManager bean configuration, it should be like this:

```
 @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```